# Leetcode ones and zeros with 3D array, fail pass sample test cases

Tags: algorithm

- I am working on leetcode [ones and zeros](https://leetcode.com/problems/ones-and-zeroes/description/).
- I tried to use a 3D array by following [this guide](https://leetcode.com/problems/ones-and-zeroes/solutions/2068639/Intuition-for-Dimension-Reduction-and-bottom-right-to-top-left-filling-of-DP-table/)

Here is my code

```
/**
 * @param {string[]} strs
 * @param {number} m
 * @param {number} n
 * @return {number}
 */
var findMaxForm = function(strs, m, n) {
    const len = strs.length;
    const dp = new Array(len+1).fill(0).map((_, i) => {
        return new Array(m+1).fill(0).map((_, j) => {
            return new Array(n+1).fill(0);
        });
    });

    const get1s = (ele) => {
        const arr = ele.split('');
        const ones = arr.reduce((acc, a) => acc + parseInt(a));
        return ones;
    }

    const get0s = (ele) => {
        const ones = get1s(ele);
        const zeros = ele.length - ones;
        return zeros;
    }

    for(let i=1; i<=len; ++i) {
        const ele = strs[i-1];
        const zeros = get0s(ele);
        const ones = get1s(ele);

        for(let j=0; j<=m; ++j) {
            for(let k=0; k<=n; ++k) {
                if(j-zeros >=0 && k-ones >= 0) {
                    dp[i][j][k] = 1 + dp[i-1][j-zeros][k-ones];
                } else {
                    dp[i][j][k] = dp[i-1][j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return dp[len][m][n];        
};
```

sample input / output

```
["10","0001","111001","1","0"]

m = 5

n = 3

expect = 4
```

Not able to pass sample test cases. Could someone have a look?

Comment: I don't get case 2. Why is '10' filtered out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. In `get1s`, the `reduce` method is called without initial value. This is a problem, because the array being iterated has strings, and so the default initial value for `acc` will be a string. This means the `+` operator will execute as a string concatenation, and not as an arithmetic operator. The fix is to provide the second argument to `reduce` (0).
2. You need to make sure you only *improve* the values in `dp`, and not "worsen" them. The blog post you referred to did this correctly with this Python code:

   ```py
   dp[i][j][k] = max(dp[i-1][j][k], 1+dp[i-1][j-cz[i]][k-co[i]]);
   ```

   In the your JavaScript version, this `max` call is not present.

Here is your code with those two corrections:

```js
var findMaxForm = function(strs, m, n) {
    const len = strs.length;
    const dp = new Array(len+1).fill(0).map((_, i) => {
        return new Array(m+1).fill(0).map((_, j) => {
            return new Array(n+1).fill(0);
        });
    });

    const get1s = (ele) => {
        const arr = ele.split('');
        // Fix: reduce must start with initial value 0:
        const ones = arr.reduce((acc, a) => acc + parseInt(a), 0);
        return ones;
    }

    const get0s = (ele) => {
        const ones = get1s(ele);
        const zeros = ele.length - ones;
        return zeros;
    }

    for(let i=1; i<=len; ++i) {
        const ele = strs[i-1];
        const zeros = get0s(ele);
        const ones = get1s(ele);

        for(let j=0; j<=m; ++j) {
            for(let k=0; k<=n; ++k) {
                if(j-zeros >=0 && k-ones >= 0) {
                    // Make sure to carry forward a DP value when 
                    //    selecting the current string brings no improvement.
                    dp[i][j][k] = Math.max(dp[i-1][j][k], 1 + dp[i-1][j-zeros][k-ones]);
                } else {
                    dp[i][j][k] = dp[i-1][j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return dp[len][m][n];        
};
```

#### Further improvements

There are some things that can be improved:

- The blog article you referred explained that you can reduce the 3D table for dynamic programming to a 2D array. The outer dimension can be omitted. You just have to ensure in the main logic, that the values are read before being overwritten: for that purpose the loops with `j` and `k` should iterate backwards.
- Once the first point is implemented, you don't need the `else` case anymore, as it will be a non-operation
- One the first point is implemented, you can remove the `if` condition and turn it into a loop condition for both loops.
- There is hardly ever a good reason to write `new Array` in JavaScript. In this case you could benefit from `Array.from` in combination with its second *mapper* argument.
- The function `get1s` should not need to convert a string to an array. You can benefit from `replaceAll` to get the required result; and then maybe it is overkill to have it as a function (debatable).

Here is the updated code:

```js
var findMaxForm = function(strs, m, n) {
    // We can re-use DP rows, so we can skip the outer dimension. 
    //    Use Array.from avoiding an intermediate array
    const dp = Array.from({length: m + 1}, () => Array(n + 1).fill(0));

    for (const ele of strs) { // We don't need variable i anymore
        // No need to convert the string to array in order to count zeros or ones:
        const ones = ele.replaceAll("0", "").length;
        const zeros = ele.length - ones;
        // Reversed iterations to make sure we read the data 
        //     from the previous outer iteration 
        for (let j = m; j >= zeros; --j) {
            for (let k = n; k >= ones; --k) { 
                dp[j][k] = Math.max(dp[j][k], 1 + dp[j - zeros][k - ones]);
            }
        }
    }

    return dp[m][n];        
};
```